# Flutter dart location library carp background locator

Tags: flutter, dart, gps

[Carp background locator](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location) library provides the method locationManger.interval = 10 ( in seconds) for gps fetch every 10 seconds, the background fetch should happen every 10 seconds, some times in android phone it is taking more than 10 seconds such as 15, 20 seconds. Is this a library issue or programmatically solvable??

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I would recommend using this [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package because it is more maintained and [carp background locator](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location) depends on a library called [background_locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator) which has some issues that are still not fixed.

also, one **important note is that these location packages required the device to be moving or changing location** this means that only if the device is moving then it will start pinging location after every 10 seconds

to use the [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package as a background service first you have to:

1. ask for permission and ensure that the location service is enabled

```
Location location = new Location();

bool _serviceEnabled;
PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
LocationData _locationData;

_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
  _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    return;
  }
}

_permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    return;
  }
}
```

2. you have to specify how often do you want the location to be fetched

```
location.changeSettings(interval: 10000, distanceFilter: 30)
```

this will ping the location every 30 meters or 10 seconds **but the device must be moving**

3. enable background mode

```
 location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);
```

on emulators and some devices the permission is enough for this on other devices this will ask you to allow location "all the time"

4. use the onLocationChanged stream from the location package and subscribe to it

```
locationStreamSubscription =
        location.onLocationChanged.listen((locationData) {
      this.updateLocation(locationData: locationData); //your function for handling location updates
    });
```

just don't forget to close the stream when disposing the widget or when you stop using it to avoid memory leaks